# Import "pybit" could not be resolved

Tags: python

When I run `pip3 install pybit` in the terminal I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pybit in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages (2.4.1)
```

But in my project:

```
#API imports
from pybit import HTTP
```

I get `Import "pybit" could not be resolved`.

How do I fix my environment?

Comment: That's a surprisingly worded error, are you sure that's coming from python and not some linter? In any case the most likely cause is that `pip3` refers to a different python than what you're running Python with. Go with `python_you_need -m pip install pybit` as per the linked duplicate.

Comment: When `python3 -m pip install pybit`, I get `Requirement already satisfied`, as mentioned above. It's the only version I have

Comment: OK, so it's definitely a linter issue. I've changed the duplicate target, please check that too. If the issue is still different I'll reopen your question, but then we'll need more details (where does the error arise, how are you running the script etc.).